# Angular - toggle only the selected element

Tags: angular, parent-child

My app structure is the following:

*parent view*

```
<ng-template ngFor let-r [ngForOf]="richieste">
<button type="button" (click)="toggleValutazioni(r)">Toggle</button>
</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="isToggledValutazioni(r)">
<app-valutazione-row [idRichiesta]="r.id"></app-valutazione-row>
</div>
```

*child typescript*

```
export class ValutazioneRowComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() idRichiesta: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    hereIsWhereIgetMyData(idRichiesta);
  }
}
```

So basically for each element of my `richieste` object I show a `Toggle` button, and when I toggle that button I show a child component. The problem is that when I toggle the button every child component shows the data of the last child component toggled. It's like every child is substituted with the last child I generated. Is there a way to make every child keep showing their infos?
Thanks.

*EDIT*
Following is the code of my toggle function.

```
toggledValutazioni: Richiesta[] = []; 

toggleValutazioni(r: Richiesta): void {
    const idx = this.toggledValutazioni.indexOf(r);
    if (idx > -1){
      this.toggledValutazioni.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
      this.toggledValutazioni.push(r);
    }
  }

  isToggledValutazioni(r: Richiesta): boolean {
    return this.toggledValutazioni.indexOf(r) > -1;
  }
```

So I already take account of the element index. The problem is that when I toggle one element I add a row of details to my view under the toggled element. When I toggle another element, I add the related row of details, but this changes the previous row of details to the last one I added.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to store the ID of the element details should be displayed for (in the button click handler logic) and then pass the respective number (or the whole element if available) to the child/detail component, e.g.:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <button 
          *ngFor="let p of data"
          (click)="toggleDetails(p.ProductID)">Product {{p.ProductID}}</button>
        <div *ngIf="detailsForIndex !== undefined">
          <product-details [product]="detailsForIndex !== undefined ? data[detailsForIndex - 1] : undefined"></product-details>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public data: any[] = products.slice(0, 10);

    public detailsForIndex;

    public toggleDetails(idx: number) {
      this.detailsForIndex = this.detailsForIndex === idx ? undefined : idx;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'product-details',
    template: `
        {{product | json}}
    `
})
export class DetailsComponent {
    @Input('product') product;
}
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPg9ALxEvEBQFa3LFrHB?p=preview)